# ASP.NET Wizard Back Button won't work

Tags: asp.net, webforms, paypal, wizard

I have a ASP.NET Wizard running my checkout process of my shopping cart.  I just added a Paypal Express checkout link to my 2nd step.  The Paypal process takes the user away from the page and then redirects them back to my wizard when they're done.  I'm parsing an HTTP parameter with Request.QueryString when the user comes back from Paypal to set the wizard to step 3.  This loads just fine, but when I click on the Back button (of the wizard), it does a postback but stays on step 3.  Can anyone think of a reason for this?  The link it's referencing still has the HTTP parameters, but I'm checking for a postback prior to programmatically setting the wizard step based on the parameter.  Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure why it was doing it, but overriding the blackbox PreviousButtonClick event on the wizard with the following code fixed it.  It seems to me like this should be the behavior the button was implementing anyway, but it wasn't.  Weird.

```
    Protected Sub wizSubmitOrder_PreviousButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles wizSubmitOrder.PreviousButtonClick
    Dim previousStepIndex As Integer = wizSubmitOrder.ActiveStepIndex - 1
    wizSubmitOrder.MoveTo(wizSubmitOrder.WizardSteps(previousStepIndex))
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this code helped with a problem that I was having with the wizard.

Comment: I was experiencing the exact same problem with the ASP.NET wizard when modifying the ActiveStepIndex based on the PayPal cancel/return querystring.  Even worse, though, I found that other postback controls (i.e. radiobuttons) on the ActiveStep failed to function correctly *if* their properties were modified from codebehind in this case.  I've seen posts in other forums indicating that the wizard can't navigate back because there is no "back" state at this point.  Given the problem with other controls, though, it seems to be more of a bug.

Comment: Fixed an issue for me too. Definitely a bug in the Wizard.